# PyMongo Query Problem: incrementing nested dict entry

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to increment an entry in a nested dict. I found that the notation for nested dicts is "firstdict.second". But "second" is a variable in my case so I prebuild the query like this:

```js
cat_query = 'categories.' + category           # build the query for the nested dict
query = {'$inc': {cat_query: trans['amount']}} # build the rest of the increment query
# exectue the query
db.months.update_one({'year': trans['date'].year, 'month': trans['date'].month}, query)
```

in the end the `query` should look like e.g. `{'$inc': {'categories.food': -300}}`
Every time I try to run the query, the mongodb crashes. The log says:

> Got signal: 7 (Bus error).

Where is the problem? Can I not use the $inc with a negative integer? Or is my query wrong?

Update: when the "categories" dict doesn't exist before running the query, it is created and everything works fine, until it tries to increment something a second time, then it crashes again.

Comment: Update: The issue was not related to the code! This was a performance issue due to the mongodb running on a rasperry pi. After switching to a cloud hosted db everything worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

My previous code did not always work correctly.

I recommend using a "sophisticated" method:

```
old_value = db.months.find_one({'year': trans['date'].year, 'month': trans['date'].month})["categories"][category]
query = {'$set': {"categories": {category: old_value + trans['amount']} }}
```

or Collections, if you need to update several categories at once:

```
from collections import Counter 
old_amounts = Counter(db.months.find_one({'year': trans['date'].year, 'month': trans['date'].month})["categories"]) # dict to Counter
now_amounts = Counter({"category_1": trans['amount_1'], "category_2": trans['amount_2'],"category_n": trans['amount_n']}) # dict to counter
new_amounts = dict(old_amounts + now_amounts) # counter to dict
query = {'$set': {"categories": new_amounts }} # update categories dict in document
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct. Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code and provide an explanation for how this code solves the problem.